# Nokia map with smartface

Tags: here-api, smartface.io

I can use Nokia map with Smartface? Does Smartface support just Google map?

Answer (score 0):

Smartface App Studio uses native map components. I mean that;

*For Android -> Google Maps
*For iOS -> iOS Map

Answer (score 0):

You can also use webviews to display Nokia maps or maps from any other providers. Even though the experience would not be as good as native, it would be fine.